# Pandas: concat dataframes

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I need merge group of dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Lic1': [0,5,7]}, index=['07:00', '08:00', '09:00'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Lic1': [4,2,1]}, index=['10:00', '11:00', '12:00'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Lic2': [1,1,4]}, index=['07:00', '08:00', '10:00'])
```

to get following result:

```
        Lic1    Lic2
07:00   0.0     1.0
08:00   5.0     1.0
09:00   7.0     NaN
10:00   4.0     4.0
11:00   2.0     NaN
12:00   1.0     NaN
```

When I use concat, I get correct columns but duplicate index (07:00, 08:00 and 10:00 due to new column name):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], sort=True, axis=0)
Output:
        Lic1    Lic2
07:00   0.0     NaN
08:00   5.0     NaN
09:00   7.0     NaN
10:00   4.0     NaN
11:00   2.0     NaN
12:00   1.0     NaN
07:00   NaN     1.0
08:00   NaN     1.0
10:00   NaN     4.0
```

and then I have to merge duplicate indices to store max values and remove duplicate rows, like this:

```
for index in df.index:
    for column in df.columns:
        df.loc[index,column] = df.loc[index, column].max()
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

which gives me requested output.

Is there any easier (==more pandastic) way how o do it in one step? I tried to do it in one step with *concat*, *merge* or *join*, but have probably missed something. I always get either duplicities in index (like above) or duplicate columns (like double Lic1 with *concat* or Lic1_x and Lic1_y with *merge*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max` per index, what is same like `.groupby(level=0).max()`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], sort=True, axis=0).max(level=0)
print (df)
       Lic1  Lic2
07:00   0.0   1.0
08:00   5.0   1.0
09:00   7.0   NaN
10:00   4.0   4.0
11:00   2.0   NaN
12:00   1.0   NaN
```